# TYPO3 Backend User Module not loading

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-8.x

With my TYPO3 8.7.29 the back-end user module suddenly stops loading.
The browsers Dev-Tool reports a 500 Internal Server Error from `https://www.example.com/typo3/index.php?M=system_BeuserTxBeuser&moduleToken=cfb67ad6cd8xxx0790d79ffc936d1fcae9d67a2e`.
The PHP error log then says:

> [10-Jan-2020 09:30:58 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error: is_callable():
>   The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an
>   incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition
>   "TYPO3\CMS\Beuser\Domain\Model\BackendUserGroup" of the
>   object you are trying to operate on was loaded *before* unserialize()
>   gets called or provide an autoloader to load the class definition in
>   /opt/typo3_src-8.7.29/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Reflection/ObjectAccess.php
>   on line 106

My PHP version is 7.2.24.

I have already tried to clear the caches including the Autoloader cache, but it did not work.

Has any of you ever had the problem and knows where it comes from?

**Workaround:**
From the List View I can still access and edit the users on the page with the id 0.

Comment: Do you have a composer based installation? And you have required "typo3/cms-beuser"?

Comment: No, my installation is not using composer.

Comment: Maybe try to run the "Reset backend user preferences" tool in "Install Tool" -> "Clean up".

Answer (score 2):

"Reset backend user preferences" fixed it for me. Thanks to @Nitori!

Comment: which version of TYPO3 are you using? 8x or newer?

Comment: I had this on different 9.5.x versions but never on 8.x.

If I remember right, it started with 9.5.9 - same base system, and after updating to a new minor version the error occurred.

Comment: I also tried to swith php version but without success.